# DB2 Query Error SQL0204N Even With The Schema Defined

Tags: db2, odbc, python

I'm using Python to access tables in DB2 10.1.0

I have a login account named foobar and a schema with the same name. I have a table named users under the schema.

When I'm logged in as foobar, I can run the following query successfully from the command line:

```
select * from users
```

I have a small Python script that I'm using to connect to the database.  The script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pyodbc

if  __name__ == "__main__":

    accessString ="DRIVER={DB2};DATABASE=MYDATABASE;SERVER=localhost;UID=foobar; PWD=foobarish1;CURRENTSCHEMA=FOOBAR" 
    print accessString
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(accessString , autocommit=True)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    query = "SELECT * FROM USERS"
    cursor.execute(query)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print 'Row data'
        print row[0]
    cursor.close()
    cnxn.close()
```

When I run the script, I get the following error:

> ('42S02', '[42S02] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0204N  "FOOBAR.USERS" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704\n (-204) (SQLExecDirectW)')

This usually means that the schema isn't defined.  However, if I change the query in the script to:

```
VALUES CURRENT SCHEMA
```

the script runs successfully and it returns

```
FOOBAR
```

I've also tried adding the schema directly to the table name, making the query

```
SELECT * FROM FOOBAR.USERS
```

and I still get the same error.

Does anyone know how to fix this so I can query the user table?  Your assistance and insight is appreciated.

Comment: An exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834390/db2-query-error-sql0204n-even-with-the-schema-defined

Comment: @mustaccio Yes - I did it intentionally because folks on DBA section may not be on SO.  Also, the problem could be coding or DB setup.

Comment: I'd confirm that the table exists in the FOOBAR schema. Does `select * from foobar.users` work from command line? What does `db2look -d mydatabase -t users -e` output? Is the schema `FOOBAR` or for example `"FOOBAR  "`, or maybe `Foobar`?  (don't know if those trailing spaces matter, but seen them sometimes). And then of course there is  `db2 list tables for all` command to list all tables (and their schemas)...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a problem with upper and lower case. I created a table using the following statement:

`CREATE TABLE "FOOBAR"."Users"  (col1 INTEGER)`

If I try try to run on of the following statements at the CLP I get an error SQL -204

`db2 "select * from db2root1.Users"`

`db2 "select * from db2root1.USERS"`

`db2 "select * from db2root1.users"`

Always the error message  SQL0204N  "DB2ROOT1.USERS" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704 is returned.

I would suggest to run the following statement and check the spelling of the table name.

`select t.tabname from syscat.tables t where lower(t.tabname) like 'user%'`

Some tools are creating the tables with a case sensitive table name. This may result in an SQL -204 in some scenarios.

In this case drop and recreate the table without any quotation marks.